# Issue concatenating 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a program that will decide if you should upgrade your computer

```
#User inputs
CPU = int(raw_input("User, input the production year of your CPU: "))
GPU = int(raw_input("User, input the production year of your GPU, if  you have a dedicated GPU: "))
buyyear = int(raw_input("User, input the year that you bought or built your desktop/laptop: "))
date = int(raw_input("User, input current year: "))

#Calculations
CPUcalc = str(date - CPU)
GPUcalc = str(date - GPU)
avgcalc = str((GPUcalc + CPUcalc + buyyear)/3)

#Outputs
if date > avg_calc:
print ("Your computer is " + avgcalc + " years old. You might not need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is slow, you may need to upgrade.")

elif date < avg_calc:
print ("Your computer is " + avgcalc + " years old. You may need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is not slow, you my not need to upgrade.")

else:
print "ERROR: The program didn't meet the requirements for the program to calculate if you need to upgrade or not."
print "The equation is: ((current year - CPU year) + (current year - GPU year) + bought year) divide by 3) = x"
print "If 'x' is less than 4, you may not need to upgrade"
print "If 'x' is more than 4, you may need to upgrade"
```

Expecting: A very long description saying if you should upgrade 
your computer or not.

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Free-Lance Coding\Computer Upgrading.py", line 10, in <module>
    avgcalc = str((GPUcalc + CPUcalc + buyyear)/3)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: You need `avgcalc =str((int(GPUcalc) + int(CPUcalc) + buyyear)/3))`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you don't have to convert values to strings and concatenate them in order to print them on the same line. `print` accepts multiple arguments and they don't have to be the same type. For example, `print "your computer is:", 10, "years old"` is valid syntax. (In Python 2.7)

Comment: @Sheldore: no, they need to drop the `str()` calls and only use those in `print`. Or just use `print "string", intvalue, "string"` instead of concatenation. Or use string formatting with `"string %d string" % (intvalue,)` or `"string {} string".format(intvalue)`.

Comment: also correct the indentation of you conditional statments if else

Comment: Why show an ERROR when `date == avg_calc` and not include this case in one of the upgrade/not upgrade cases? What is `avg_calc` computing? Shouldn't it be `date - buyyear`? Why ask the user for the current year not let Python do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are converting your values to strings too soon, assuming you want to be able to print `CPUcalc`, `GPUcalc` and `avgcalc` later on. You are trying to make a calculation with `GPUcalc` and `CPUcalc` but those values are strings, when they really don't need to be.

Only convert values to strings when they *have* to be strings:

```
CPUcalc = date - CPU
GPUcalc = date - GPU
avgcalc = (GPUcalc + CPUcalc + buyyear) / 3
```

You also have a typo, you reference both `avgcalc` and `avg_calc`. Presumably only `avgcalc` exists:

```
if date > avgcalc:
    print ("Your computer is " + str(avgcalc) + " years old. You might not need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is slow, you may need to upgrade.")

elif date < avgcalc:
    print ("Your computer is " + str(avgcalc) + " years old. You may need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is not slow, you my not need to upgrade.")

else:
    print "ERROR: The program didn't meet the requirements for the program to calculate if you need to upgrade or not."
    print "The equation is: ((current year - CPU year) + (current year - GPU year) + bought year) divide by 3) = x"
    print "If 'x' is less than 4, you may not need to upgrade"
    print "If 'x' is more than 4, you may need to upgrade"
```

Note that you don't need to use `str()` to convert values to strings, that's only needed when concatenating non-string objects with strings. You can have `print` convert values to strings for you if you pass them to the statement separately (at which point `print` inserts spaces between each element):

```
if date > avgcalc:
    print "Your computer is", avgcalc, "years old. You might not need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is slow, you may need to upgrade."

elif date < avgcalc:
    print "Your computer is", avgcalc, "years old. You may need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is not slow, you my not need to upgrade."

else:
    # ...
```

You can also use string formatting, with the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
if date > avgcalc:
    print "Your computer is {} years old. You might not need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is slow, you may need to upgrade.".format(avgcalc)

elif date < avgcalc:
    print "Your computer is {} years old. You may need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is not slow, you my not need to upgrade.".format(avgcalc)

else:
    # ...
```

The `{}` placeholder will convert values to a suitable string, or you can further configure how the value should be treated.

Note that your actual tests (`date > avgcalc`, `date < avgcalc`) and the text you print in the `else` branch don't agree with one another, where you say you test the calculation against the number `4`.

Your calculation also doesn't make all that much sense, why would you add the year the computer was bought to the number of years that have passed since the CPU and GPU have been bought? You probably want to use `(date - buyyear)` in the `avgcalc` value. I'd also use the term `age` in each variable, to make it clearer what the values *mean*:

```
CPU_age = date - CPU
GPU_age = date - GPU
computer_age = date - buyyear
avg_age = (CPU_age + GPU_age + computer_age) / 3

if avg_age > 4:
    # computer is old
else:
    # computer is still new enough
```

Your `else:` branch doesn't make all that much sense, as that'd only happen if `date` and `avgcalc` were to be exactly equal. You probably want to learn about [validating user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) and use the error message there.

You can also consider using Python to get the current year, computers usually know the date already. Python has the `datetime` module, where [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) gets you today's date, and the resulting object has a `year` attribute:

```
import datetime

# ...

date = datetime.date.today().year
```

Last but not least: if you are learning Python, it is **strongly** recommended that you switch to Python 3. Python 2, the language you are using now, will reach end-of-life January 2020, a [little over 8 months from today](https://pythonclock.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You have following issues: 
 - Difference between print statement `print "Test"` in python 2 and `print("test")` in python 3 
 - indentation problem after if else statements 
 - Variable name mismatch `avgcalc` and `avg_calc` 
 - Concatenating `avgcalc` with string to print 
etc

Here is the working code but really you need to learn about python and difference between `raw_input()` and `input()` method , `print` and `print()` in terms of python versions.

**if you use Python 3:**

```
#User inputs
CPU = int(input("User, input the production year of your CPU: "))
GPU = int(input("User, input the production year of your GPU, if  you have a dedicated GPU: "))
buyyear = int(input("User, input the year that you bought or built your desktop/laptop: "))
date = int(input("User, input current year: "))

#Calculations
CPUcalc = date - CPU
GPUcalc = date - GPU
avgcalc = (GPUcalc + CPUcalc + buyyear)/3

#Outputs
if date > avgcalc:
    print("Your computer is " + str(avgcalc) + " years old. You might not need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is slow, you may need to upgrade.")

elif date < avgcalc:
    print("Your computer is " + str(avgcalc) + " years old. You may need to upgrade your laptop/desktop, but if you think your laptop/desktop is not slow, you my not need to upgrade.")

else:
    print("ERROR: The program didn't meet the requirements for the program to calculate if you need to upgrade or not.")
    print("The equation is: ((current year - CPU year) + (current year - GPU year) + bought year) divide by 3) = x")
    print("If 'x' is less than 4, you may not need to upgrade")
    print("If 'x' is more than 4, you may need to upgrade")
```

**If you are using python 2:**

replace `input()` with `raw_input` and replace print("Your string") with `print "your string"` in above code.

Comment: The parentheses around the string being printed is not really much of an issue if they don't use commas to separate elements.

Answer (score -1):

try this :
avgcalc = (GPUcalc + CPUcalc + buyyear)/3

avgcalc = int(avgcalc)